# How to inherit lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have inherited Master Pages and Theme from parent site. Seems like one page in the parent site is using list to display the content.

In the subsite when I select FAQ from Page Layout the page will show FAQList from parent site. I want to create new FAQ list for subsite and want to show it on this page.

I know I might have to edit FAQ.html here masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx but I am unable to understand how to replace parent site list with subsite list?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing the current FAQ.html, I suggest you create a custom page layout for the subsite, then choose it on the subsite.

Example of creating a custom page layout in SharePoint Online:

https://ravichandran.blog/2016/06/12/create-custom-page-layout-for-sharepoint-online/